# Proyecto symfony en puerto 8000 funciona bien en puerto 80 no (Sylius)

Tags: symfony3, sylius

Estoy utilizando la plataforma [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) se instala y funciona correctamente.
Lo que sucede es que la misma trabaja con el propio servidor de symfony en el puerto 8000 con estas lineas:

```
php bin/console server:start
open http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Entonces cuando quiero trabajar con el puerto 80 utilizando solo la ruta del servidor local que tengo.

```
http://localhost/ven/web
```

No funciona nada a veces queda en blanco a veces muestra algún error y a veces simplemente muestra la pagina distorsionada.

Que solución le puedo dar a este problema?

Comment: ¿en qué sistema operativo trabajas?

Comment: Windows pero luego voy a subir el desarrollo aún servidor con Centos

Comment: Antes que todo asegurate de que no tienes nada escuchando en el puerto 80, ejecuta `resmon.exe` y busca en el apartado "Puertos de escucha" de la pestaña "Red".

Comment: Es que si se que estoy escuchando por el puerto 80 eso necesito. Lo que necesito es que se vea bien en esta ruta: http://localhost/ven/web

Comment: Disculpa, me expliqué mal, que no estés escuchando ningún otro programa/servicio

Comment: No ningun otro programa está escuchando. Esta solo activo xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando server:start abre el puerto 8080 por defecto, usa el comando de esta manera para habilitar el puerto 80 (o el que te interese

```
php bin/console server:start localhost:80
```

Ten en cuenta que este servidor embebido [no es apto para producción](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html).

Comment: Entiendo esto pero si lo que quiero es utilizar el servidor xammp local o como indicas cuando este en producción como debería hacer para que funcione??

Comment: En ese caso, olvídate del servidor embebido, y usa un servidor web (Apache o Nginx, por ejemplo) debidamente configurado. Tienes amplia información sobre ello [aquí](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) En el caso de XAMP, basta con que configures un vhost y lo apuntes a la carpeta web de symfony, tal como te indica el enlace anterior.

Comment: Configure un vhost a la carpeta web y sale la página en blanco pero lo mismo ejecuto con esa línea de código al puerto 8000 o al 80 como indica en la respuesta y funciona perfecto eso es lo especial de este caso. Sin embargo lo voy a volver a revisar.

Comment: El problema lo encontre en los logs pero me dio mucha luz tu respuesta. Gracias faltaba instalar la libreria intl de php luego de esto todo funciona bien, esto es sencillo aca esta explicado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41340205/2400373